# MS EXCEL - Lookup/Check for multiple columns values in other sheet

Tags: excel, vlookup, data-analysis

## Ex:Data

## [image: sheet1]

## [image: sheet2]

***What I want to do***

I need to validate, if sheet1 data is present in sheet 2

Ex: check if IBM.N with value 52.35 is present in sheet2

Thanks in Advance

Comment: `=countifs(Sheet2!A:A, A2, Sheet2!B:B, B2)>0` will spit out true or false if you stick it in Sheet1 C2

Comment: You could also use `=vlookup(A2, Sheet2!A:B, 2 false)=B2`

Comment: Perfect!! =Countifs is working like a charm. Thanks much @JNevill

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
=countifs(Sheet2!A:A, A2, Sheet2!B:B, B2)>0
=vlookup(A2, Sheet2!A:B, 2 false)=B2
```

***Credits***:JNevill